# Show a mapping is a contraction mapping

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to show the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}( x + \sin x + \frac{1}{x+1})$ is a contraction mapping on $[0,\infty)$

I've tried arguing as follows: $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{3} ( |x-y| + |x-y| + \frac{|x-y|}{(x+1)(y+1)})$, where the middle term is by the MVT, however this doesn't seem like a contraction as we can't bound the last term on the whole interval.

EDIT: I had mistyped the original function, it is now correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not a contraction.

Your $f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, with derivative
$$
f'(x)=\frac13+\cos x-\frac1{(x+1)^2}.
$$
So at $x=2n\pi$, we have $f'(x)=\frac43-(2n\pi+1)^{-2}>1$, so by MVT,
$$
f(2n\pi+\varepsilon)-f(2n\pi)=\varepsilon\cdot\lvert f'(2n\pi+\theta\varepsilon)\rvert>\frac54\varepsilon
$$
for sufficiently large $n$ and sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$.

---

**Edit**: With the correction, you have
$$
f'(x)=\frac13\left[1+\cos x-\frac1{(x+1)^2}\right]
$$
and on $x\in(0,\infty)$, we have $\lvert (x+1)^{-2}\rvert <1$, $\lvert \cos x\rvert\leq 1$.  Hence the triangle inequality gives $\lvert f'(x)\rvert<1$ and thus $f$ contracts distance by MVT.  However, it isn't a contraction in the sense of contraction mapping theorem, because $f'(x)\to 1$ as $x\to 0+$.

Comment: Sorry, had mistyped the function, I've edited it now